# Check if promise is resolved before passing to image src

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to asyc load a bunch of logos.

Vue code

```
<template v-slot:item="{ item }">
    <v-list-item-avatar v-if="logo(item.Code, item.Exchange)">
      <v-img :src="logo(item.Code, item.Exchange)"></v-img>
    </v-list-item-avatar>
</template>
```

JS code

```
async logo(code, exchange){
      let hostname = window.location.hostname
      let logoURL = `http://${hostname}/backend/logo/${code}.${exchange}`
      let response = await fetch(logoURL)
      let url = await response.json()
      return url
},
```

Right now I'm getting the error

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "src". Expected String, Object, got Promise
```

How do I make it wait till the promise is resolved before displaying the image?

Answer (score 1):

The `async` function always return a `Promise` object, that's why you have the type check error. To use the returned `url` of your `async` function. You can declare a variable and when the `async` function responses, assign the responses value to that variable:

```
let urlLogo = "";

logo(item.Code, item.Exchange).then(url => urlLogo = url);
```

Comment: Is the urlLogo a global variable? I'm loading multiple logos so it can't be a global variable. Also I don't get what .then is doing.

Comment: Then I suggest you to learn about `Promise` carefully before using `async/await`, because `async/await` is `Promise`with different syntax. Please follow this link to learn more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: `Is the urlLogo a global variable?` => it's up to you, base on your code context and situation.

Comment: This answer does not give a working solution, only a basic suggestion that may or may not solve this complex question.  It would be helpful to show how it could actually be used in the template, using async data, based on a slot prop.